# Is there any JavaFX method to protect my application for anticracking?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Java Swing application that could be cracked and I'm looking for an alternative.
Is there any JavaFX method to protect my application for anti cracking?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is just a UI framework; preventing cracking isn't one of the design goals or intentions of the framework.

If you want to prevent cracking, look into [obfuscators or AOT compilation](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html).